# Unknown error while parsing Json data from url

Tags: python-2.7

while parsing below code, I am getting unknown BaseException as ' search-results' or 'citedby-count' for some of the queries which are perfectly similar to other queries.

Thanks in advance.

```
            params = get_connection_parameters(title)
            r=requests.get(params[0],headers=params[1],timeout=60)
            response = r.content
            data = json.loads(response)

            try:
                c_data = data['search-results']['entry'][0]['citedby-count']
                value = row.strip("\n")+','+str(c_data)
                output.write("\n"+value)
            except BaseException as b:
                print(b)
```

json data to be parsed:

```
{"search-results":{
    "opensearch:totalResults": "1",
    "opensearch:startIndex": "0",
    "opensearch:itemsPerPage": "1",
    "opensearch:Query": {
        "@role": "request",
        "@searchTerms": "TITLE(daime, a novel image analysis program for microbial ecology and biofilm research)",
        "@startPage": "0"
    },
    "link": [
        {
            "@_fa": "true",
            "@ref": "self",

        },
        {
            "@_fa": "true",
            "@ref": "first",

        }
    ],
    "entry": [
        {
            "@_fa": "true",
            "prism:url": "https://api.elsevier.com/content/abstract/scopus_id/33644868597",
            "eid": "2-s2.0-33644868597",
            "dc:title": "daime, a novel image analysis program for microbial ecology and biofilm research",
            "citedby-count": "298"
        }
    ]
}
```

}

Comment: You should inspect the JSON and see if those fields are even present in the error code. Even print debugging might help here.